# Referring to type in instance declaration

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to use undefined to get value of type constant (something like `sizeOf` in storable).

```
module Main where

class MyClass a where
    typeConst :: a -> String
    -- ^ Argument is ignored

class TryRead a where
    tryRead :: String -> Maybe a

newtype ByLen a = ByLen a

-- | Make all types under ByLen readable, if their typeConst's are longer then 3 characters
instance (Read a, MyClass a) => TryRead (ByLen a) where
    tryRead = if len > 3
                then Just . ByLen . read
                else const Nothing
      where
        len = length $ typeConst (undefined :: a)

instance MyClass Int where
    typeConst = const "moreThan3"

main :: IO ()
main = go (tryRead "214234" :: Maybe (ByLen Int))
  where
    go Nothing = print "Nothing :("
    go (Just (ByLen i)) = print i
```

However, this gives an error:

```
Could not deduce (MyClass a0) arising from a use of ‘typeConst’
from the context (Read a, MyClass a)
  bound by the instance declaration at src/Main.hs:13:10-49
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance MyClass Int -- Defined at src/Main.hs:20:10
In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
  ‘typeConst (undefined :: a)’
In the expression: length $ typeConst (undefined :: a)
In an equation for ‘len’: len = length $ typeConst (undefined :: a)
```

I don't understand what problem with type deducing is there, considering I specified type for `typeConst` argument explicitly as `a` type variable, which is bound by `MyClass a`, so it should in my mind have no problems applying to `typeConst` function.

Comment: You need to use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension: otherwise the `a` in the `where` clause is not recognized as being the same one as the one bound before but rather a fresh type variable (hence the `a0` vs. `a` issue).

Comment: @gallais Thanks, that works. Now waiting for someone to write it as an answer. But I read some about this extension and I now don't get why is it working without explicit `forall`? (I tried something like that inside non-class function and it didn't. compile until I added a `forall`)

Comment: My guess is that an instance declaration is a bit of a special case: if you declare `instance forall a. (...) => MyClass (Maybe a)` for instance then you get a `Malformed instance` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `ScopedTypeVaribales` extension to be enabled for this to work either through a `ghc` flag `-XScopedTypeVariables` or through a pragma at the top of the file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

If it used within a class instance, nothing special needs to be done, because type variables from the head of the class are already in the scope, but if you would like to use it in simple top level function you will need an explicit `forall` in the type signature.